# multiple select boxes, get selected values using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a grid with each row having a drop down list to select a state.
What I want to do is upon submit of the form, grab each value selected (if none skip over)

```
<select name="state" class="dd1">
<option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

Now I can have up to 50 rows with the same  select object in each row.

Currently I have the following put together that sort of works.

```
function UpdateCustomers()
{
  var getStatesUpdated = $("select.dd1").each(function (i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() > 0) {
           return $this.val();
        }

  });

}
```

I say the above sort of works because if I put in a alert box in the above if statement, it lists each value selected.  My goal here is to return a string of states comma delimited so getStatesUpdated would look like this if I selected 3 states out of 50 rows.

```
getStatesUpdated = "CO,MI,FL";
```

How can I return each selected item in a comma delimited string?

Thanks so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<select> tag and returning multiple values to javascript method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256486/select-tag-and-returning-multiple-values-to-javascript-method)

Comment: @ChristianFelix: OP means to have the value of multiple select elements... Not multiple values of one element.

Comment: A return in `each` does not return to outer variable and neither does it create an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) does not return a string as you seem to expect... But is returning `jQuery`... Read, the collection of the `select.dd1` elements.

You should declare an array in the `updateCustomers` function... Then use `.each()` to loop the elements, then return a string made of the array elements joined with comas...

```js
function UpdateCustomers() {
  var getStatesUpdated = [];
  $("select.dd1").each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() !== "0") {
      getStatesUpdated.push($this.val())
    }
  });
  return getStatesUpdated.join(",")
}

$("button").click(function(){
  console.log(UpdateCustomers());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="state" class="dd1">
  <option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

<select name="state" class="dd1">
  <option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

<select name="state" class="dd1">
  <option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

<button>Log selected</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `map()` , `filter()` and `join()`

```js
function UpdateCustomers() {  
  return $("select.dd1").map(function () {
    return this.value;    
  }).get().filter(function(val){
      return val !== "0"
  }).join();  
}

$("button").click(function(){
  console.log(UpdateCustomers());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="state" class="dd1">
  <option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
  <option value="AL" selected>Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

<select name="state" class="dd1">
  <option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK" selected>Alaska</option>
</select>

<select name="state" class="dd1">
  <option value="0">Select A State (optional)</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

<button>Log selected</button>
```

Comment: Charlitfl ... your solution is more efficient coding wise...didn't see it till after I awarded the response above.  Thank you for spending the time.  I'll definitely be using this solution

Comment: It's quite acceptable to change your choice of accepted answer when a better one appears